# Getting BASH command PID

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, pipe, pid

I have this piece of code

```
#!/bin/bash
streamURL=http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8

(
    echo "Debugging for stream: $streamURL";
    echo "Starting debugging...";
    vlc -vvv --color $streamURL --file-caching=10000 2>&1 | sed "s/^/ `date`/";

) | tee  debug.txt &
PROCESS_PID=$!

ps -e | grep $PROCESS_PID 
echo " killing process pid: "
echo $PROCESS_PID;
kill -9 $PROCESS_PID
ps -e | grep vlc #still there
```

My problem is I can't manage to save the "vlc ..." command PID into a variable in order to kill it later. If I move "**PROCESS_PID=$!**" right after it, it will be empty. Also need the pipe after it for **sed**. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mbratch in the code above, the PID I get is coming from the "tee" command

Comment: Why do you want the pid?  If you are just planning to send a signal after a fixed period of time, it is probably much simpler to use `timeout` or put the `vlc` command inside a wrapper script that does the timeout for you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I didn't have knowledge of `timeout` as I'm at the begining with bash. thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the pid by twiddling file descriptors, but it's painful.  For example:

```
{ PID=$({ ( 
   echo foo; 
   echo bar;
   sh -c 'echo $$ >&5; exec echo baz' ) |
   tr a o; } 5>&1 1>&3 ); } 3>&1
```

will assign the pid of 'echo baz' to PID.  Replace that echo with your `vlc` and replace the `tr` with your `sed` and you should have a solution.

To try an provide a somewhat simplified explanation of what's going on here, first notice that we are using process substitution to make the assignment to `PID`.  The `$()` syntax simply takes the command inside the parentheses and assigns to the variable the output of the command.  It is important to remember that "output" here means "whatever is printed to file descriptor 1".  Inside the `sh` command, we print a pid to file descriptor 5 and then exec `echo`.  By using exec, that echo has the same pid that the previous echo wrote.  Now the echo foo, bar and baz are all writing into  the pipe that goes to tr.  The output of tr is being redirected to fd 3 (before the edit, this was fd 2. Which file descriptor to use is mostly arbitrary, but modifying 2 is a bad idea in case any errors are generated) and file descriptor 5 is being redirected to fd 1, so that it becomes the "output" of the process substitution that is assigned to PID.  Then outside the process substitution, we assign fd 3 to give output where it was originally desired.  Hopefully, this paragraph is more explanatory than obfuscating: if confused, look at the code for clarification!

Unfortunately, it gets uglier if you want to run in the background:

```
{ PID=$({ ( 
   echo foo; 
   echo bar;
   sh -c 'echo $$ >&5; exec 5>&-; exec echo baz' >&3 & ) |
   tr a o; } 5>&1 1>&3 ); } 3>&1
```

Here, you need to close file descriptor 5 to ensure that the process substitution completes.

Comment: Wow, my head is spinning. Having problems understanding it (bash newbie) ^^

Comment: Yeah, it's fairly obscure.  I'll try to add an explanation, but the code really does speak for itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a variable in a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) and [get it back outside it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done).

In this case, if you `kill $!` you'll kill `tee`, which will (AFAIK) send `SIGPIPE` to the subshell and terminate the whole thing. So there's generally no need for the PID in the subshell.

I'm not sure, but the problem might be that you're [nuking the process from orbit with SIGKILL](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...) rather than killing it softly with just `kill $PID`. It might be that `tee` does *not* send SIGPIPE in this case, because it doesn't get to clean up after itself.

In other words, just use `kill $process_id`. Be aware that killing a process is not synchronous - you're just sending it a signal and carrying on. See [Kill bash processes “nicely”](https://superuser.com/questions/222318/kill-bash-processes-nicely) for details.

Comment: Just tried it but it doesn't seem to work: I get tee's pid but killing it won't also kill vlc

Comment: Please update the question with the code you're using to kill the process.

Comment: What I want to do is let the process run for about 20 seconds using sleep, the kill it, especially vlc and after that continue with parsing the log. This will repeat every minute so I really have to clean the trash :)

Comment: Actually it's working just like you said, but I need to use **kill 0 PROCESS_PID**. Thanks

Comment: `kill -0` (with a dash) does *not* kill the process, it just checks that it's still alive. `kill 0 $PROCESS_PID` will try to kill PID 0 *and* `$PROCESS_PID` (should be `$PROCESS_ID`, if anything).

Comment: wops my bad, seems: 0  = All processes in the current process group are  signaled.